# AssetBundle memory device

Tags: c#, unity3d, память

Как проверить, достаточно ли количество памяти на устройстве для загрузки АссетБандлов?
И как получить размер АссетБандла?

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос с помощью

Caching.currentCacheForWriting.maximumAvailableStorageSpace